# ERROR message: "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

Tags: plugins, errors, user-access

I have this problem, I've completely deleted all plugins, themes and changed php to 7.1. Nothing is helping. I have the same message:
 "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."
Are there other areas I can check and see if it works?

Comment: That email should have the error specified at the bottom. What is it?

Comment: That's part of the problem...... No email

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when one of your WordPress files contains an error and error reporting is turned off. Easy fix is to change the value of the `WP_DEBUG` constant in `wp-config.php` to `TRUE`. This would turn on error reporting and errors would be displayed instead of the generic message.

Remember to change the value back to `false`. A truthful value is only necessary in development environments.

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall WP (don't overwrite your wp-config.php file). Then reinstall all themes/plugins from original source. You may have to do this with FTP if you don't have access to admin area. Although FTP is slower (depends on your connection speed), that will ensure that all files have latest versions.

Then, use File Manager to look at all folders, sorting by date, looking for files that don't match the datestamp of the other files (since you updated everything). Look for files that don't belong. Could be a hack attempt.

Test the mail() function by creating a simple PHP page with a valid mail() command. Make sure that your admin email account is of the same domain as the site. If the admin account is a different domain name than your site, mail messages will be not sent by your server or caught as spam.

Comment: Thanks Rick, will try it

Comment: Post a followup on the actual solution. Helps others who stop by here. (And, if I helped, a checkmark is always appreciated.) Good luck.